# Self-modifying code problems with change permisions

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am writing self-modifying code. I try to change the address permission of my function to be execute, but when I try to migrate my code written in Dev C++ to Visual Studio 2017 I got an error.

I am using Microsoft Windows 10, and Visual Studio 20017 for this task with default configurations.

```
int change_page_permissions_of_address(void *addr) {
    // Move the pointer to the page boundary
    int page_size = getpagesize();
    DWORD dwOldProtect;
    addr -= (uintptr_t)addr % page_size;

    if (VirtualProtect(addr, page_size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    char *foo_addr = (char*)foo;

    if (change_page_permissions_of_address(foo_addr) == -1) {
        printf("Error while changing page permissions of foo(): %s\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    // Call the unmodified foo()
    puts("Calling foo...");
    foo();

    // Change the immediate value in the addl instruction in foo() to 42
    unsigned char *instruction = (unsigned char*)foo_addr + 18;
    *instruction = 0x2A;

    // Call the modified foo()
    puts("Calling foo..., but I am the self-modifying");
    foo();
    }
}
```

I want to have the same behaviour as dev c++ in visual studio

error

> Error (active)    E0852   expression must be a pointer to a complete object
>   type
>   Error C2036   'void *': unknown size

[image: overwrite_mutation]

Comment: 2 `main` ???!!!

Comment: `VirtualProtect` returns a `BOOL`, not `-1`. Also see [VirtualProtect function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

`addr -= (uintptr_t)addr % page_size;` is the problem.
`-=` on a pointer subtracts the left side as an integer times the size of the thing the pointer points to and subtracts it from the pointer. The compiler is complaining because it doesn't know the size of void.

Can you make the parameter a `char *`?

Comment: not at all because if I change to char then my main function it will make incompatible parameter for the void *foo_addr = (void*)foo;

Comment: Same suggestion. Make foo_addr a char *.

Comment: if I change to char then my main function it will make incompatible parameter for the void *foo_addr = (void*)foo; , and it will print always value 1 orignal and mutation 1 . So my mutation result should be overwritten with my value in this case 42

Comment: @yesii_0691: `addr = ((char*)addr) - ((uintptr_t)addr) % page_size;`.

Comment: Or maybe a bit operation: `addr &= ~(uintptr_t)(page_size-1);`.

Comment: @jww: No, pointers are pointers, not numbers (despite appearances to the contrary). You cannot perform bitwise arithmetic on them, nor does it generally makes sense to do so.